# Powershell: Record files moved to log file, via write-log

Tags: logging, powershell, archive

Caveat: My Ignorance - apologies

I would like to write to a log file with a function: "Write-Log"
e.g.

```
Write-Log -Message "moved file abcd.efd" -Path C:\MyLog.log
```

(Stolen from http://poshcode.org/2566)

I am successfully log writing, from an archiving script, with the Write-Log function, which I have added via a . include.

I would like to note to my log file, via Write-Log, which files have been archived.

Current archive details are:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceDir |
Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime.Date -lt (get-date).AddDays(-$Age) -and -not $_.PSIsContainer} |
Move-Item -Destination $MoveDir
```

How may I plug in my Write-Log to record those files I have archived?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call Move-Item and Write-Log from within the ForEach-Object cmdlet for each fileinfo object returned from Get-ChildItem.
Example:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceDir | `
Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime.Date -lt (get-date).AddDays(-$Age) -and -not $_.PSIsContainer} | `
ForEach-Object {
$fileInfo = $_
Move-Item -Path $fileInfo -Destination $MoveDir -WhatIf
# Log your message
Write-Log -Message "moved file $fileInfo" -Path C:\MyLog.log
}
```

Comment: thnx, works for me. FYI/FWIW 1) $fileInfo.fullname 2) I'm sure I saw a similar answer and a subsequent post objected to the foreach on the end of a pipeline - meh - ne'er mind, it works and number of files i'm shifting don't think i'm in the realm of looking to increase performance... 'agin tar.